Setting hx-disabled-elt not disabling my button
I am trying to disable a button with htmx 2.0.2.
I have a typical form with a button:
    <button type="submit"
            tags="prominent,login"
            class="btn btn-primary w-full"
            hx-disabled-elt="this">Sign In</button>

When I click the button, the hx-disbled-elt does not put the button in a disabled state.
I have tried to make the hx-disabled-elt a bunch of different values: this, #btn, this.form.button. None of them work.
How do I make this work?

what version of htmx are you using? that feature was introduced in 1.9.6

version - 2.0.2

Per the documentation:

The hx-disabled-elt attribute allows you to specify elements that will have the disabled attribute added to them for the duration of the request.

You are not making a request here. As a result, nothing gets disabled.
You need to add a target to make a request. Only then will the button be disabled while the request is in flight. E.g.
    <button type="submit"
            tags="prominent,login"
            class="btn btn-primary w-full"
            hx-post="/signup"
            hx-disabled-elt="this">Sign In</button>


ht-get="/signup" isn't a request?. Also in the docs don't have an hx-target on the sample code

@jhamm I'm confused. Where do you have ht-get="/signup"? I can't find that in your question? And it's not in my answer. I use hx-get not ht-get.

I never said it had to be hx-get, anything triggering a request will do. hx-post is on the example, which also works and is more canonical for a button. It doesn't matter with regards to your question.
